# java string to varbinary

Tags: java, sql-server-2008-r2

#### background

I have an android client which sends image as string base64 to a jersey web service, then I want to save this image into my sql servier 2008 r2 database. I want to convert that string to varbinary.

#### my question

how to convert string to varbinary

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JDBC maps varbinary to byte arrays. So this means that you first have to convert your base64 String to a byte array. This is what any Base64 implementation does. You just have to pick one.

With [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html#decodeBase64%28java.lang.String%29), for example, you would something like:

```
String myEncodedImage = "...";
byte[] myImage = Base64.decodeBase64(myEncodedImage);
```

And then you would simply pass that byte array to your persistency layer, JDBC will take care of the rest.